# How to change lightsails database timezone

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

We have a database server (mysql) in AWS LightSail an the timezone is UTC we instead need CET/CEST.
The given user is not permitted to change thid.
How can we instead do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update some database parameters on Lightsail via AWS CLI

below are 2 references on how to achieve this. Parameter names vary according to the Database and version. So update your parameter accordingly.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-update-database-parameter/

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-updating-database-parameters#get-database-parameters